# Expressjs collection.update $push result with TypeError: Cannot call method 'update' of undefined

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, geojson

I try to create valid geojson FeatureCollection and some problems occurred during updating document in collection.

My Model

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var DataSchema = new Schema({
  type: {type:String, default:"Feature"},
  properties:{
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true},
  date: {type:Date, default:Date.now}},
  geometry:{
  type:{type:String, default:"Point"},
  coordinates: {type: [Number]}}
  });

  var MetadataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type  : {type: String, default: "FeatureCollection"},
    features: [DataSchema]
  });

 var rescueModel = mongoose.model('rescueModel', MetadataSchema);
```

Router

```js
router.post('/mountain_rescue', function(req, res){
  db.collection('rescuemodels', function(err, collection){
    collection.update({
      "type": "FeatureCollection"
    },
    {
      $push: {
        "features": {
          properties: {
            title: req.body.title,
            description: req.body.description
          },
          geometry: {
            coordinates: req.body.coordinates.split(',')
          }
        }
      }
    });
  res.redirect('/mountain_rescue');
  });
});
module.exports=rescueModel;
```

So If everything is okay but why is it that after executing post route I get

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'update' of undefined

I also checked the command in mongo shell and it works

```js
db.rescuemodels.update(
    {
       "type":"FeatureCollection"
    },  
    {
       $push:{
           "features": {
               "properties":{"title":"WOW"} 
            } 
       } 
    }
)
```

Comment: Offtopic but FYI: Setting the object type to `Feature Collection` isn't valid GeoJSON, `FeatureCollection` is. http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-collection-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `collection` is not defined before running the update. Also, you might want to do the redirect in the callback to the `update` function, but that will depend on the behaviour you are looking for. Your code would then look something like this:

```js
var collection = db.collection('rescuemodels');
collection.update({
  "type": "FeatureCollection"
},
{
  "$push": {
    "features": {
      "properties": {
        "title": req.body.title,
        "description": req.body.description
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": req.body.coordinates.split(',')
      }
    }
  }
}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    res.redirect('/mountain_rescue');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that by typing// db.collection('rescuemodels', function(err, collection){ Sth i do with collection } //  then i can use collecion already as argument from function? By the way I use it in the same why with GET and i don't have any problems when specifying findOne or findById ? Why is that? Could you explain.

Comment: You're absolutely right. However, using that syntax is primarily useful with `{strict: true}`, which ensures that the collection exists, and with the appropriate error handling, `assert.equal(null, err)`, etc. If you log the errors, it should shed light on why works in some places and not in others. Otherwise if you know the collection exists, I would recommend using `db.collection('collection')` to assign a collection to a variable or run a query directly. More info [here](https://thomashunter.name/blog/mongodb-node-js-driver-collection-select-doesnt-require-callback/).